# add line break in mobile sms

Tags: php, mobile, sms, line-breaks

I am working with an API of a certain sms service and I just want to know how to add a line break from php code in a plain text format to mobile?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question but anyway it might help someone.

I tend to use `PHP_EOL` for this purposes (due to cross-platform compatibility).

`echo "line 1".PHP_EOL."line 2".PHP_EOL;`

If you're planning to show the result in a browser then you have to use `"<br>"`.

Comment: have found this answer, after trying and failing with (\n, '\n', "\n", \r\n, '\r\n', "\r\n", \\n, '\\n', "\\n", \\r\\n, '\\r\\n', "\\r\\n"). PHP_EOL worked at once.

Answer (score 9):

```
$text = "This is line 1.\nThis is line 2.";
```

Be sure to use double quotes around the string, not single quotes.

If that's not working, you'll need to talk to the folks who made the API.

Comment: Hi ceejayoz, I have already tried it but still it does not work.

Comment: Talk to the folks providing the API, then.

Answer (score 6):

If nothing working try with `%0a` like bellow:

```
$sms = 'This is line 1%0aThis is line 2';
```

Comment: Correct! Only this one worked. I want to add that if you wish to add multiple line breaks, consider adding a space between the two as %0a %0a

Answer (score 2):

Try with : "\r\n"
and also don't forget to enclose your message with double quotes.

It will work, if not the link below have more ways, try them...

https://codeupweb.wordpress.com/2017/07/18/how-to-add-a-line-break-in-sms-message/

Answer (score 1):

If API is HTTP based, then you should use [url-encoded LF](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp). If It isn´t work then you should use [GSM-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38).

Answer (score 1):

you should use `\n` ,try this

```
 $sender->sendMessage("Vocabulary:\n".$word.$meaning,$test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It better to start with double quote it work fine. Do not use single quote

***Use this example below to capture your idea***

$message = "This is my message \n This is my second message"

Answer (score 0):

I use clicksend api , and The `"<br>"` tag works correctly.